# How to implement protocol optional method in Struct?

Tags: swift, struct, protocols, swift4

I have defined optional method in Movable Protocol

```
 @objc protocol Movable
 {
   @objc optional func move(to point: CGPoint)
 }
```

Now, I am trying inherit same protocol wth Struct but compiler is complaining with below given lines.

**Error:-Non-class type 'Shape' cannot conform to class protocol 'Movable'**

```
 struct Shape: Movable
 {
     func drawShape(){
         print("DrawShapped Called")
     }
     func move(to point: CGPoint) {
        print("Struct Movable called")
     }
 }
```

And, It is working completely fine if  I am inheriting Movable protocol in some class rather than struct.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I would suggest moving away from the @objc/optional prefix and giving a default implementation to the protocol, making that way the conformance to a specific method of the protocol optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you mark a protocol as `@objc`. You implicitly mark that protocol as a `class` protocol. That is, it must be implemented by a class. Because in objective-c, a struct cannot implement a protocol.
try changing it to

```
class Shape: Movable
{
    func drawShape() {
        print("DrawShapped Called")
    }
    func move(to point: CGPoint) {
       print("Struct Movable called")
    }
}
```

or mark do not mark `Movable` as `@objc`

Comment: so, Is there any way to achieve optional delegate feature with struct ? @tungsten

Comment: No, there is not. Default implementations achieve almost all of the same goals. (There has been some discussion about adding `optional` into non-objc protocols, since it is slightly different in some corner cases and slightly more convenient, but I don't think there's been a big push for it.)

Comment: I believe under the hood `optional` functions are implemented using `respondsToSelector:`, which means it needs to conform to `NSObjectProtocol`, which means it can't be a struct.

Answer (score 3):

As Swift Rabbit notes in the comments, the better solution here is a default implementation:

```
protocol Movable {
    func move(to point: CGPoint)
}

extension Movable {
    func move(to point: CGPoint) {} // Do nothing by default
}
```

You should avoid adding `@objc` to things unless you need to interact with ObjC code. If this protocol must interact with ObjC code, then you cannot conform to it with a struct, and you'll need to make `Shape` a class.